# How to feed a Google Calendar?

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api, feed

I am using this sample to feed my calendar. I have created a Client ID but after I run this project I get 2 errors in console as is shown:

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = '633454716537-7npq10974v964a85l2bboc2j08sc649r.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      // This quickstart only requires read-only scope, check
      // https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth if you want to
      // request write scope.
      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES,
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load Calendar client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadCalendarApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Google Calendar client library. List upcoming events
       * once client library is loaded.
       */
      function loadCalendarApi() {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var events = resp.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming events:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }

        });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to calendar</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Console errors:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (auth, line 0)
[Error] Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=633454716537-7npq10974v964a85l2bboc2j08sc649r.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay396521106&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=file%3A%2F%2F&response_type=token&state=338793751%7C0.4135151437&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. (about:blank, line 0)
```

All I want to know is to show the upcoming events from my calendar.
Have anyone any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to make sure it is a public calendar.

You can also embed googles calendar in a webpage directly- in calendars/settings

You could also try something like this: 
http://mikeclaffey.com/google-calendar-into-html/